# Site not found using subdomains

Tags: multisite

Hello i am having a few problems setting up subdomains on my multisite install. I was hoping someone could point out any ways that i have went wrong. Thanks.

My website doesnt site on the root. Its in a subfolder public_html/onlinebanter.co.uk

DNS setting-
[image: redirect]

public_html/onlinebanter.co.uk/wp-config.php

```
/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'onlinebanter.co.uk');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On^M
RewriteBase /^M
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]^M
^M
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin^M
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]^M
^M
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]^M
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d^M
RewriteRule ^ - [L]^M
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]^M
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]^M
RewriteRule . index.php [L]# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
```

getting a not found at this site address
http://test.onlinebanter.co.uk/

Is there anything that i have done wrong? I only set up the wildcard thingy about 6hrs ago. Could it be waiting to propogate?

thanks

Comment: sorry i should mention that i a using the latest 3.81 version of wordpress.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a DNS problem, not WordPress. `ping test.onlinebanter.co.uk` displays `unknown host`. WordPress does not even handle the requests because the client is unable to determine the IP address of the server and therefore does not send the HTTP request.

`ping www.onlinebanter.co.uk` works, so I assume the name server did not properly store the DNS configuration (yet). Depending on the setup, your provider might need some time to apply the new configuration to the name server. Make sure that you activated (or however it's called in your configuration interface) the changes.

Comment: ah hah all working now still learning. It must just have been a timescale thing. Thanks for your help :)